# what does __asm__("movl %eax,%esp") return?

Tags: c, linux

here is a little function on a old book:

```
unsigned long f()
{
   __asm__("movl %eax,%esp");
}
```

the function explained to get the stack point,but it seems not.It actually gets a 8-bit address much lower than my frame address.I guess it's designed for 32-bit system?
Please forgive me if I said something stupid.

Comment: Use 'rax' and 'rsp' for 64-bit

Comment: ...and anyway, probably %esp is always _lower_ than the frame address...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, as @James mentioned in the comments, in 64 bit mode, `%eax` and `%esp` represent the least significant 32 bits of the 64 bit `%rax` and `%rsp` registers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code has some mistake

```
unsigned long f()
{
__asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}
```

it provides the stack pointer address